# How to set background image on PosterGridView

Tags: roku, brightscript

I'm using a PosterGridView and display multiple posters in Roku. I use a transparent image in a poster. Is there any way to change background Like white or blue using a poster grid?
[image]

I used poster grid view like below :

```
<PosterGrid 
id = "ChannelPosterGrid" 
translation = "[ 10 , 10 ]" 
caption1NumLines = "2" 
caption2NumLines = "2"
numColumns="4"
numRows="6"
focusBitmapUri="pkg:/images/imagegrid.png"
itemSpacing = "[ 20, 20 ]" />
```

In a .brs file access like simply :

`m.top.grid = m.top.findNode("ChannelPosterGrid")`

I have tried three things :

```
m.top.grid.backgroundURI = "pkg:/images/myImage.jpg" 'not work
m.top.backgroundURI = "pkg:/images/myImage.jpg" 'not work
scene.backgroundURI = "pkg:/images/white.jpg" 'Its set hole screen background 'scene is object of roSGScreen
```

**EDITED:**

Here, I set an image using hdposterurl and sdposterurl. But, Here I getting a transparent image with black color. And My background is also black. So, The Image is mixed-up with the background. So, I required to find a way to put a white rectangle behind of image. It's Possible with RowList. Because of the Poster node used inside a RowList. But, I try to find out with PosterGrid.

I tried this field(imageWellBitmapUri). But, It does not work with Empty Poster Grid in my case. I tried to put a white image or Rectangle behind the black transparent images. I required it because here my images are black transparent and my background is also black. So, Images Merged with the background. I want to do something like this in the PosterGrid. Here Sample in Poster Node.

```
<Rectangle id="testRectangle" color="0xFFFFFFFF">
<Poster id="poster"/>
</Rectangle>
```

Comment: You need to set the image for your content for the poster grid. For more refernce. https://developer.roku.com/docs/references/scenegraph/list-and-grid-nodes/postergrid.md#data-bindings

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I already set an image using hdposterurl and sdposterurl. But, Here I getting a transparent image with black color. And My background is also black. So, The Image is mixed-up with the background. So, I required to find a way to put a white rectangle behind of image. It's Possible with RowList. But, I try to find out with PosterGrid.

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% clear to me what you are asking here

> I use a transparent image in a poster. Is there any way to change background Like white or blue using a poster grid?

[posterGrid](https://developer.roku.com/docs/references/scenegraph/list-and-grid-nodes/postergrid.md) component doesn't have a `backgroundURI`  field that I can find.

I know that you can use a `rectangle` component to make a colored background at any position and relative z-index on the screen.  If you want to use a `.jpg` then you could also create a new child component `poster` and insert it where needed.  The child insertion order determines the z-index.  If you're trying to add it to an `itemComponent` then you may need a level of hacking to get that working, but lmk.